# Generate Multi-dimensional Array Based off HTML Headers with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, domdocument, php-7

First off, I'm certain it's something obvious that I should've caught hours ago, but I just can't seem see it.

## Situation

So, the situation is that I'm trying to setup a reusable (not recursive) function to parse a block of HTML into a multi-dimensional array split by the header elements. Basically, the end result should be no more than 7 levels (H1-6 and the children of the H6). There's also a catch for any elements before the first H1 to be placed into a "special" section labeled "Top".

## Code

```
<?php
    function sortEntrySections($section, $level = 1) {
        if(is_array($section)) {
            $i = 0;
            $ele = 'h' . $level;
            $sectionStructure = $level === 1 ? array(array('title' => 'Top', 'children' => array())) : array();
            foreach($section as $element) {
                if($element->tagName != $ele && isset($sectionStructure[$i]) && is_array($sectionStructure[$i])) {
                    array_push($sectionStructure[$i]['children'], $element);
                } else {
                    $i++;
                    if($element->tagName == $ele) {
                        $sectionStructure[$i] = array('title' => $element->textContent, 'children' => array($element));
                    } else {
                        $sectionStructure[$i] = $element;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $sectionStructure;
        }
        return $section;
    }

    function breakupEntry() {
        $body = new DOMDocument();
        @$body->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(html_entity_decode($GLOBALS['libraryEntry']['body']), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $formattedBody = new DOMDocument();

        /* Build Multidimensional Array of Sections */
        $i = 0;
        $elements = array();
        foreach($body->getElementsByTagName('*') as $child) {
            if($child->tagName !== 'html' && $child->tagName !== 'body' && $child->parentNode->tagName === 'body') {
                array_push($elements, $formattedBody->importNode($child, true));
            }
        }
        $sections = sortEntrySections($elements, 1);
        for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($sections); $i++) {
            $childrenH1 = sortEntrySections($sections[$i]['children'], 2);
            if(isset($childrenH1['children'])) {
                foreach($childrenH1['children'] as $j => $childH1) {
                    $childrenH2 = sortEntrySections($childH1, 3);
                    if(isset($childrenH2['children'])) {
                        foreach($childrenH2['children'] as $k => $childH2) {
                            $childrenH3 = sortEntrySections($childH2, 4);
                            if(isset($childrenH3['children'])) {
                                foreach($childrenH3['children'] as $l => $childH3) {
                                    $childrenH4 = sortEntrySections($childH3, 5);
                                    if(isset($childrenH4['children'])) {
                                        foreach($childrenH4['children'] as $m => $childH4) {
                                            $childrenH4[$m]['children'] = sortEntrySections($childH4, 6);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $childrenH3['children'][$l] = $childrenH4;
                                }
                            }
                            $childrenH2['children'][$k] = $childrenH3;
                        }
                    }
                    $childrenH1['children'][$j] = $childrenH2;
                }
            }
            $sections[$i]['children'] = $childrenH1;
        }
        return $sections;
    }

    $body = <<<EOD
<p>Pre Header Section Content 1</p>
<p>Pre Header Section Content 2</p>
<p>Pre Header Section Content 3</p>
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Header 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h2>Header 1.1</h2>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h3>Header 1.1.1</h3>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h4>Header 1.1.1.1</h4>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h5>Header 1.1.1.1.1</h5>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h6>Header 1.1.1.1.1.1</h6>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h6>Header 1.1.1.1.1.2</h6>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h6>Header 1.1.1.1.1.3</h6>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h5>Header 1.1.1.1.2</h5>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h5>Header 1.1.1.1.3</h5>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h4>Header 1.1.1.2</h4>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h4>Header 1.1.1.3</h4>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h3>Header 1.1.2</h3>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h3>Header 1.1.3</h3>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h2>Header 1.2</h2>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h2>Header 1.3</h2>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<p>Header 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h1>Header 3</h1>
<p>Header 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 3 Section Content 3</p>
EOD;
    $libraryEntry = array('body' => $body);

    $results = breakupEntry();

    echo '<textarea>'; var_dump($results); echo '</textarea>';
?>
```

## Results

https://pastebin.com/JLftvXdB

## Expected

https://pastebin.com/tzqxu8q4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote this thing half a dozen times, each giving a different problem I kept getting stuck on. In the end, I rewrote it as a limited recursive function, using restrictions on the `$level` variable to ensure it didn't exceed the intended range.

```
<?php
    function sortEntrySections($section, $level = 1) {
        if(is_array($section)) {
            $i = 0;
            $level = intval($level);
            $level = $level > 6 ? 6 : ($level < 1 ? 1 : $level);
            $ele = 'h' . $level;
            $sectionStructure = $level === 1 ? array(array('title' => 'Top', 'children' => array())) : array();
            foreach($section as $element) {
                if($element->tagName != $ele && isset($sectionStructure[$i]) && is_array($sectionStructure[$i])) {
                    array_push($sectionStructure[$i]['children'], $element);
                } else {
                    $i++;
                    if($element->tagName == $ele) {
                        $sectionStructure[$i] = array('title' => $element->textContent, 'children' => array($element));
                    } else {
                        $sectionStructure[$i] = $element;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach($sectionStructure as $i => $subsection) {
                if(is_array($subsection) && isset($subsection['children']) && $level < 6) {
                    $sectionStructure[$i]['children'] = sortEntrySections($subsection['children'], $level + 1);
                }
            }
            return $sectionStructure;
        }
        return $section;
    }

    function breakupEntry() {
        $body = new DOMDocument();
        @$body->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(html_entity_decode($GLOBALS['libraryEntry']['body']), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $formattedBody = new DOMDocument();

        /* Build Multidimensional Array of Sections */
        $i = 0;
        $elements = array();
        foreach($body->getElementsByTagName('*') as $child) {
            if($child->tagName !== 'html' && $child->tagName !== 'body' && $child->parentNode->tagName === 'body') {
                array_push($elements, $formattedBody->importNode($child, true));
            }
        }
        $sections = sortEntrySections($elements);
        return $sections;
    }

    $body = <<<EOD
<p>Pre Header Section Content 1</p>
<p>Pre Header Section Content 2</p>
<p>Pre Header Section Content 3</p>
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Header 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h2>Header 1.1</h2>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h3>Header 1.1.1</h3>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h4>Header 1.1.1.1</h4>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h5>Header 1.1.1.1.1</h5>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h6>Header 1.1.1.1.1.1</h6>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Section Content 3</p>
<h6>Header 1.1.1.1.1.2</h6>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h6>Header 1.1.1.1.1.3</h6>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h5>Header 1.1.1.1.2</h5>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h5>Header 1.1.1.1.3</h5>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h4>Header 1.1.1.2</h4>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h4>Header 1.1.1.3</h4>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h3>Header 1.1.2</h3>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h3>Header 1.1.3</h3>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h2>Header 1.2</h2>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h2>Header 1.3</h2>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 1 Subheader 3 Section Content 3</p>
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<p>Header 2 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 2 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 2 Section Content 3</p>
<h1>Header 3</h1>
<p>Header 3 Section Content 1</p>
<p>Header 3 Section Content 2</p>
<p>Header 3 Section Content 3</p>
EOD;
    $libraryEntry = array('body' => $body);

    $results = breakupEntry();

    echo '<textarea>'; var_dump($results); echo '</textarea>';
?>
```